# Firefox doesn't show the 'title' attribute

Tags: javascript, firefox, attributes, title

I have created a little tooltip framework, which works fine in all modern browsers. There's one thing that really bugs me: in Firefox this seems to disable displaying a regular title (from the `title` attribute).

I can't find a cause for this. It's not the `mouseover` handler that I assign for certain elements, because on regular (non handled) elements, titles are not displayed either. Furthermore, I experimented with this (see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7Hqb/), and it was not replicable).

Can this be some known Firefox bug (I searched the Internet for that, but I didn't find anything relevant) or am I doing something wrong in my scripting, HTML, or CSS?

I've put the whole thing in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/m2b8Y/embedded).

[**edit april 2022**] This is a very old question. *Do* disregard it.

Answer (score -1):

*title* is displayed in my Firefox, and Firefox doesn’t have any bug regarding the same. Try updating your Firefox, or maybe some plugin in your browser may be causing the tooltip to hide.

Comment: I use FF 10.0.1, disabled all add ons to check, still no titles are displayed. Did you use http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/m2b8Y/embedded (the 'result' tab)?

Comment: What version of Firefox was it?